# How to change the default user name for shell in Mac OS

Tags: macos, shell, ssh

I have my Mac setup with username XXX.
And when I do my job, I need to ssh/scp to a remote server with username YYY (I use iTerm 2 and bash shell).

It's really annoying to specify the username YYY@hostname each time I login to the workstation, since the YYY is long (12 characters).

Is there any solution to change/specify the default user name from XXX to YYY of the shell, **without changing my Mac username**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the file `$HOME/.ssh/config`, and add something like this:

```
Host HOSTNAME
  User YYY
```

Replace all the upper case parts. Now you can just do `ssh HOSTNAME` and it will use YYY as the username.

To have this apply to all hosts that you use with SSH, you can do:

```
Host *
  User YYY
```

And also, if you want to specify a shortened hostname with the ssh command, you can:

```
Host YOUR-NAME-FOR-THE-HOST
  HostName ACTUAL-LONG-HOSTNAME-WITH-DOMAIN-NAME
  User YYY
```

Then you can just run `ssh YOUR-NAME-FOR-THE-HOST` and it will connect to the full hostname you specified.